# Unable to send email from contact form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Before, the Contact Form 7 worked as it supposed. But lately, after submitting the form it responds with an error message as: “There was a problem sending the message. Please try again later.”, with red borders.

I am using the Default WordPress mailing.

Wordpress: Version 5.4.2
Contact Form 7: Version 5.1.9

Please help to find a solution to this. Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow really isn't the place for this sort of question... you'd be better served in the Contact Form 7 support forum. Questions on StackOverflow need to include enough specific information about the problem, include a minimal reproducible example of the code, and show what you've tried so far to fix it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Just contact your hosting company and tell them about this issue.
or
You can install [WP SMTP Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

After installing and activating plugin, just select any mailer option and create an account their to get an API.
After getting API, feed this to smtp plugin options and check for test email.
I hope, this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same as above and I have used Gmail as a mailer option but I got the below error.
EMAIL DELIVERY ERROR: the plugin WP Mail SMTP v2.1.1 logged this error during the last time it tried to send an email:

Mailer: Gmail
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)